# Closed form of sum involving binomial coefficients having to do with odd perfect numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, perfect-numbers

Okay, so I am working on a proof of the upper bound of the odd perfect numbers. The following is what I have so far, and now I am stuck.

If $n$ is an odd perfect, it satisfies the following property:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{⌊n/2⌋}\binom{2n-2j}{n}\left(\binom{2n}{j}-\sum_{d|n,d<n}\binom{2d}{j}\right)=J(n)(\sigma(n)-2)$$

Where $J$ is somewhat "well-defined". They are the coefficients of a $2n$ degree polynomial $P$
$$
P_{2n}(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n}J(k)z^k=\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(z-r_i);J(0)=1
$$

such that
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(1-\frac{1}{r_i})^{-1}=0$$ $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(1-\frac{1}{r_i})=0$$ $$\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(1-\frac{1}{r_i})^{-1}=1$$

Is there a closed form solution to the following expression from above:

$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{⌊n/2⌋} \binom{2n-2j}{n}\binom{2n}{j}$$

I have researched various papers on binomial sums and identities and cannot seem to find anything that can help besides hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Why do you think that's interesting or useful?

Comment: Its part of a much bigger proof I am working on involving bounds on odd perfect numbers.

Comment: If you wrote so in your question, it might be upvoted instead of downvoted.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this site. Ive edited by question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be in the OEIS.
Maple gives me a hypergeometric expression

$$ {2\,n\choose n}
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(-2\,n,-n/2,-n/2+1/2;\,-n,-n+1/2;\,-1)}
$$